# Converting text to lowercase/uppercase with a pending a radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a Javascript program that takes a users input text, then (pending a radio button check – lowerCase/UpperCase) converts the input text to either lowercase/upperCase and outputs the value back to the form.

Purely trying to learn on my own Javascript. I am moderately new (but savvy) to JS. Pretty solid on HTML, CSS, Java, but BRAND new with interacting with page elements.

I have dug around for two days to try and solve this. I have even checked out a few books at my local library. (Currently reading the text, Microsoft guide to CSS/HTML, and JS). What other books would you recommend in order to under JS more?

Here is the code below. Although I know one can use CSS in order to convert this and I have done this. I'm purely just wanting to figure out Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
 <title> Case Changer By: Elliot Granet</title>

 <style>
 function convert(){
  var convertedText = document.test.input.value;
    if(document.getElementById("lowerCase").checked = true){
      var output = convertedText.toLowerCase();
       }else {
       output = convertedText.toUpperCase();
       }
    document.getElementById('outputText').value = output;
}
convert();

</head>
```

The rest -

```
<body>
<h3>Choose your Conversion method below:</h3>
<form action="getElementById">
  <fieldset>
<input id="lowerCase" type="radio" name="case" value="lowerCase">Lower Case<br>
<input id ="upperCase" type="radio" name="case" value="upperCase">Upper Case<br><br>
    </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
<textarea id="inputText" name="input" form="inputText">Enter text here to be Converted...</textarea>
    </fieldset><br>
  <fieldset>
<textarea id ="outputText" name="output" form="outputText">Converted text will appear here...</textarea>
    </fieldset>
  <input type="button" value="Convert">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <style> is incorrect put it snippet inside <script> tag

Comment: You need to call your function in response to a click event on the radio buttons. Also, as in Java, = does an assignment, and == does a comparison. So check your if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make few changes to make this function work.

1. `style` is an invalid tag to put js code. You need to put it inside `<script>` tag
2. If you are writing this function inside `header` yo may come across error since  before DOM is ready it will try to get value of textarea with id inputText.
3. `document.getElementById(idName').value` but not  is right syntax to get the value of  element using id
4. Attaching `convert()` with the button. So when you will click on button the function will execute.
   5.`document.getElementById("lowerCase").checked = true` this is wrong.It mean that checkbox will get checked as `=` will assign the value . Instead you need to compare the value. So use `==` or `===`
5. if you declare `var output` inside `if` loop it wont be available inside `else`. So you need to declare it outside the `if-else` loop

Hope this snippet will be useful

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Convert" onclick="convert()">
```

JS

```
    window.load =convert; // convert function will be called after window is ready
    function convert(){
     var output; //variable declaration outside if-else loop
      var convertedText = document.getElementById('inputText').value; //document.getElementById

        if(document.getElementById("lowerCase").checked == true){   // == comparision
          output = convertedText.toLowerCase();
           }
           else {
           output = convertedText.toUpperCase();
           }


   document.getElementById('outputText').value = output;
}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/yot75gpg/5/)